# How to use JemmyFX from Jython?

Tags: javafx, jython, jemmy, jemmyfx, jython-2.7

I am exploring the possibility of using JemmyFX from Jython by attempting to port `tests/bigapps/EnsembleTest` to Jython.  But, I have encountered an obstacle.  I expect to be able to replace this Java code:

```
TextInputControlDock searchField = new TextInputControlDock(
    mainToolbar.asParent(),
    TextField.class);
```

With this Jython code:

```
searchField = TextInputControlDock(
    mainToolBar.asParent(),
    CriteriaList([TextField.__class__]).getCriterias())
```

However, with the Jython code I have provided, the search for the `TextField` control times out with an `org.jemmy.TimeoutExperiedException`.

I can work around this particular instance by modifying the source to the Ensemble demo to give the `TextField` and ID, and then search for the `TextField` by ID.  However, I encounter the very same problem only a few lines later with a search for a `ContextMenu`, and in this case, giving the `ContextMenu` an ID does not work.

Comment: JemmyFx is dead use TestFX

Comment: Things have moved much more quickly on TestFX.